# get s3 files with prefix using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My s3 filename is 'folder/filename.xml'. i want to take the files end with 'name.xml'

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
try:
fileobj = s3.Object('lcu-matillion',''folder/.*name.xml'').get()['Body']

data=fileobj.read()
except Exception:
  print('not found')
```

Any one please help with accurate code?
Thanks

Comment: Use the `glob` module in the standard library (but you probably need `*`, not `.*`).  https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: By the way, `except Exception` is dangerous, do you think every exception in opening a file is "not found"?

Comment: Side-note: You could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command with `--include`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't forget that there could be multiple files that match that wildcard.

You would use something like:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='folder-name/')

for object in objects:
  if object.key.endswith('.txt'):
    object.download_file('/tmp/' + object.key)
```

Comment: This is dangerously inefficient. -1

Comment: Agreed -- using a filter would reduce the number of objects returned. Checking for a suffix would still require a loop within the `if`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: OK +1 now! Thanks

Comment: It should be object.Object().download_file('/tmp/' + object.key)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty OLD one and I am at loss that the main answer which has been accepted is a very poor and potentially dangerous one.

This essentially lists ALL objects and brings searching to the client side. On a bucket with thousands of objects (I guess most buckets) that is terrible.

What you need to do is to use `.filter()` instead of `.all()`:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
buc = s3.Bucket("twtalyser")
for s in buc.objects.filter(Prefix='my/desired/prefix'):
    print(s)
```

## UPDATE

The main answer was updated to reflect the point I was making.